# React-Redux - Fetching data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Im trying to use Firebase to catch some data and display on my web app, but I'm not understanding how to do it. I'm using reduxThunk.
Im getting the error **id is not defined**.
This is my component

**trabalhos.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';


class Trabalhos extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    renderList({id,tec,title}){
        return(
            <li className="list-group-item" key={id}>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p>{tec}</p>
            </li>
        )
    }

    render(){
    return (

        <div>
            <div className="trabalhos">
                <div className="trabalhos_caixa">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <ul className="no_pad">
                                {this.renderList()}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

}


function mapStateToProps(state){

return { fetch: state.fetch };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Trabalhos);
```

this is my Action

**actions/index.js**

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import { FETCH_DATA } from './types';

const Data = new Firebase('https://portofoliofirebase.firebaseio.com');

export function fetchData(){
return dispatch => {
    Data.on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_DATA,
            payload: snapshot.val()
        });
    });
}

}
```

this is my **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reducers from './reducers';
import routes from './routes';
import * as **firebase** from 'firebase';
import **reduxThunk** from 'redux-thunk'

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
</Provider>
, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

This is my **fetch_reducer.js**

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = [], action) {
switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_DATA:
        return action.payload.data;     
}

return state;
}
```

This is my Reducer **index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import fetchReducer from './fetch_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({

fetch: fetchReducer

});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Where is the Trabalhos component getting its props set? Do you intend for that to be a connected component?

Comment: i have updated !!

Comment: @Hseleiro Where is that error coming from? Is your firebase app working? From the docs, it looks like you have to run initializeApp before Firebase is active. Also, you have to call `.on()` on a `firebase.database().ref()` to listen for changes. I don't think you can call `.on()` directly on the firebase instance (links below).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: @Shane Thanks for the help, when i run initializeApp i get the error : Uncaught TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function(…)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `this.renderList()` without any arguments, so `id` at `<li className="list-group-item" key={id}>` indeed `is not defined`. I guess maybe you want to use `this.props.payload.data.map(this.renderList)`?

Comment: `this.props.payload.data.map(this.renderList)` was a hunch about what you are trying to do. You should replace by the correct prop name.

Comment: Thank leo, but its not working, im trying use _ lodash